# How to disable -werror while using ESP32 and FreeRTOS

Tags: build, freertos, esp32, cflags

I'm trying to connect with Amazon FreeRTOS using ESP32 and I've got a problem with building this. I'm doing everything according to tutorial on Amazon website (for Windows). The error is

> cc1.exe: some warnings being treated as errors.

I found that the solution might be disabling -werror. To do so I've tried to paste this line:
`string(REPLACE " -Werror" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")`
into CmakeLists.txt file in main AmazonFreeRTOS folder. Didn't help :/ .

My CmakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# Disable in-source build.
if("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source build is not allowed, please use a separate build folder.")
endif()

project(amazon-freertos)
set(PROJECT_VERSION "201906.00 Major")
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR "201906")
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR "00")

# Import global configurations.
include("tools/cmake/afr.cmake")

#disabling -werror
string(REPLACE " -Werror" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}") 

# Add 3rdparty modules.
add_subdirectory("libraries/3rdparty")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure target board
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get list of supported boards.
afr_get_boards(AFR_SUPPORTED_BOARDS)

set(AFR_BOARD "vendor.board" CACHE STRING "Target board chosen by the user at configure time")
set_property(CACHE AFR_BOARD PROPERTY STRINGS ${AFR_SUPPORTED_BOARDS})

string(REGEX MATCH [[(.+)\.(.+)]] __match_result ${AFR_BOARD})
set(AFR_VENDOR_NAME ${CMAKE_MATCH_1} CACHE INTERNAL "MCU vendor name")
set(AFR_BOARD_NAME ${CMAKE_MATCH_2} CACHE INTERNAL "MCU board name")

# Abort if the target board is not supported, i.e., corresponding folder is not present.
if(NOT AFR_BOARD IN_LIST AFR_SUPPORTED_BOARDS)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Board is not supported: ${AFR_BOARD}")
endif()

# Import board CMake build.
set(AFR_VENDOR_PATH "vendors/${AFR_VENDOR_NAME}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
include("${AFR_VENDOR_PATH}/manifest.cmake")
if(DEFINED AFR_MANIFEST_BOARD_DIR_${AFR_BOARD_NAME})
    set(AFR_BOARD_PATH "${AFR_VENDOR_PATH}/${AFR_MANIFEST_BOARD_DIR_${AFR_BOARD_NAME}}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
elseif(DEFINED AFR_MANIFEST_BOARD_DIR)
    set(AFR_BOARD_PATH "${AFR_VENDOR_PATH}/${AFR_MANIFEST_BOARD_DIR}/${AFR_BOARD_NAME}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not import board CMakeLists.txt.")
endif()
add_subdirectory("${AFR_BOARD_PATH}")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Amazon FreeRTOS modules
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Initialize all modules.
add_subdirectory("libraries")
add_subdirectory("demos")
add_subdirectory("tests")

# Resolve dependencies.
afr_status("=========================Resolving dependencies==========================")
afr_resolve_dependencies()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Summary
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
afr_status("")
afr_status("====================Configuration for Amazon FreeRTOS====================")
afr_status("  Version:                 " "${AFR_VERSION}")
afr_status("  Git version:             " "${AFR_VERSION_VCS}")

# ================ Target microcontroller =================
afr_status("")
afr_status("Target microcontroller:")

afr_get_board_metadata(vendor_name VENDOR_NAME)
afr_get_board_metadata(board_name  DISPLAY_NAME)
afr_get_board_metadata(description DESCRIPTION)
afr_get_board_metadata(family      FAMILY_NAME)
afr_get_board_metadata(data_ram    DATA_RAM_MEMORY)
afr_get_board_metadata(program_mem PROGRAM_MEMORY)

afr_status("  vendor:                  " "${vendor_name}")
afr_status("  board:                   " "${board_name}")
afr_status("  description:             " "${description}")
afr_status("  family:                  " "${family}")
afr_status("  data ram size:           " "${data_ram}")
afr_status("  program memory size:     " "${program_mem}")

# ===================== Host platform =====================
afr_status("")
afr_status("Host platform:")

afr_status("  OS:                      " "${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM}")
afr_status("  Toolchain:               " "${AFR_TOOLCHAIN}")
afr_status("  Toolchain path:          " "${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
afr_status("  CMake generator:         " "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")

# ================ Amazon FreeRTOS modules ================
afr_status("")
afr_status("Amazon FreeRTOS modules:")

afr_status("  Modules to build:        " "${AFR_MODULES_BUILD}")
afr_status("  Enabled by user:         " "${AFR_MODULES_ENABLED_USER}")
afr_status("  Enabled by dependency:   " "${AFR_MODULES_ENABLED_DEPS}")
afr_status("  3rdparty dependencies:   " "${3RDPARTY_MODULES_ENABLED}")
afr_status("  Available demos:         " "${AFR_DEMOS_ENABLED}")
afr_status("  Available tests:         " "${AFR_TESTS_ENABLED}")

afr_status("=========================================================================")
afr_status("")

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Demos and tests
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Enable us to use targets defined in vendor CMake files.
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)

if(TARGET aws_demos)
    list(TRANSFORM AFR_DEMOS_ENABLED PREPEND "AFR::" OUTPUT_VARIABLE demos_list)
    target_link_libraries(aws_demos PRIVATE ${demos_list})
endif()

if(TARGET aws_tests)
    list(TRANSFORM AFR_TESTS_ENABLED PREPEND "AFR::" OUTPUT_VARIABLE tests_list)
    target_link_libraries(aws_tests PRIVATE ${tests_list})
endif()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Output metadata information
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(AFR_METADATA_MODE)
    afr_write_metadata()
endif()
```

So pls someone tell me how to disable -werror or some another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had very similar issues and with the help of the most excellent FreeRTOS folk tried the following:

1) Check configSUPPORTSTATICALLOCATION is set to 1 in
FreeRTOSConfig.h. – The nnnCreateStatic() functions won’t be available otherwise.

2) Ensure FreeRTOS.h and then queue.h or tasks.h  are included (as
appropriate) at the top of the offending .c file. Check the warnings to id that file.

Number 1 sorted out out for me.